# I want to collect all the user answers ( checked radios and checkboxes) and see if the user has selected the correct answer. If so, score++

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, javascript-objects, addeventlistener

The code isn't doing what I would like it to. I'm sure something is missing but don't know what. When I click the "check score" button I would like it to show the score but for now, it only shows "You scored: 0/10. My displayScore() function doesn't work.
Could anyone tell me what I'm missing here? Observe that there is two possible correct answers for the questions with checkboxex.

```js
(function () {
  function renderQuiz() {

    const quizContainer = document.querySelector("#quizContainer");
    let quizStr = '';

    // Loops over the object properties (obj) and also takes an index parameter
    quiz.forEach((obj, questionIndex) => {
      // Empty string to keep the li element containing the label and input
      let answerStr = '';
      //Loops over the options object inside of the array quiz
      for (const option in obj.options) {
        /* If it has an object that has an array as a value it renders the inputs as checkboxes */
        if (Array.isArray(obj.correct) === true) {
          answerStr += `
                  <li>
                  <label>
                  <input 
                  value=""
                  type="checkbox"
                  name="question-${questionIndex}"
                  data-correct="${obj.correct}"
                  >
                  ${obj.options[option]}
                  </label>
                  <li> `;
          /* Else it renders the inputs as radiobuttons */
        } else {
          answerStr += `
                  <li>
                  <label>
                  <input 
                  type="radio"
                  name="question-${questionIndex}"
                  data-correct="${obj.correct}"
                  >
                  ${obj.options[option]}
                  </label>
                  <li> `;
        }
      }
      quizStr += `
          <form>
              <h3>${obj.question}</h3>
              <ul>
              ${answerStr}
              </ul>
          </form> `;
    })

    quizContainer.innerHTML = quizStr;
  }

  const resultsContainer = document.querySelector("#results");
  // Adds held score to total and displays a text with the score
  function displayScore() {

    const answerContainer = [];

    quiz.forEach((obj, questionIndex) => {

      let userAnswer = `input[name="question-${questionIndex}]:checked`;
      let answers = [];

      if (userAnswer >= 2) {
        userAnswer.forEach(e => {
          let selected = e.target.userAnswer;
          answers.push(selected);
        })
      } else {
        answers = userAnswer[0];
      }
      answerContainer.push(answers);
    });

    let score = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < quiz.length; i++) {
      let correctAnswer = quiz[i].correct;
      let userChoice = answerContainer[0];

      if (Array.isArray(correctAnswer)) {
        if (JSON.stringify(correctAnswer) === JSON.stringify(userChoice)) {
          score++;
        }
      } else if (correctAnswer === userChoice) {
        score++;
      }
    }

    resultsContainer.innerHTML = `<p>You scored : ${score} / ${quiz.length}</p>`;
  }

  // Objects with question sections within an array
  let quiz = [
    {
      question: "I vilket land produceras det mest kaffe?",
      options: {
        a: "Kolombia",
        b: "Brasilien",
        c: "Indonesien",
        d: "Vietnam"
      },
      correct: "b"
    },
    {
      question: "I vilket land konsumeras det mest kaffe?",
      options: {
        a: "Italien",
        b: "Belgien",
        c: "Finland",
        d: "Kanada"
      },
      correct: "c"
    },
    {
      question: "Ordet kaffe betyder vin på det språket det härstammar ifrån. Vilket språk är det?",
      options: {
        a: "Arabiska",
        b: "Ryska",
        c: "Turkiska",
        d: "Grekiska"
      },
      correct: "a"
    },
    {
      question: "Hur många kalorier finns i en kopp kaffe?",
      options: {
        a: "1",
        b: "5",
        c: "14",
        d: "7"
      },
      correct: "a"
    },
    {
      question: "Vem upptäckte kaffet?",
      options: {
        a: "En bonde",
        b: "En fåraherde",
        c: "En munk",
        d: "En jägare"
      },
      correct: "b"
    },
    {
      question: "På vilket djurs avföring är världens dyraste kaffe gjord på?",
      options: {
        a: "Mus",
        b: "Fågel",
        c: "Apa",
        d: "Katt"
      },
      correct: "d"
    },
    {
      question: "När kom kaffet till Sverige?",
      options: {
        a: "1700-talet",
        b: "1800-talet",
        c: "1400-talet",
        d: "1600-talet"
      },
      correct: "d"
    },
    {
      question: "Vilka två av dessa alternativ är typer av kaffe?",
      options: {
        a: "Arabica",
        b: "Mocca",
        c: "Robusta",
        d: "Java"
      },
      correct: ["a", "c"]
    },
    {
      question: "Välj de enda två delstaterna i U.S.A som odlar kaffebönor?",
      options: {
        a: "Georgia",
        b: "Kalifornien",
        c: "Hawaii",
        d: "Florida"
      },
      correct: ["b", "c"]
    },
    {
      question: "Hur förvaras kaffe som bäst? Välj två sätt.",
      options: {
        a: "Svalt",
        b: "I kylskåp",
        c: "Öppet",
        d: "Mörkt"
      },
      correct: ["a", "d"]
    }
  ];

  renderQuiz();

  let checkButton = document.querySelector("#check");
  checkButton.addEventListener("click", displayScore)
})();
```

Comment: It's hard to work with your code with only the scripting. Please adjust your question to include the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript for this so we can interact with it as it runs.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the HTML and CSS:
(ignore the div with the id toggleBtns and the content of it)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.0/css/all.css">
   <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   <title>Kaffe Quiz</title>
</head>
<body>
   <main>
       <div id="toggleBtns">
           <button id="black" class="btn active">Black</button>
           <button id="milk" class="btn">Milk</button>  
       </div>
       <section id="quizSection">
           <h1><i class="fas fa-mug-hot"></i>Kaffe Quiz<i class="far fa-lightbulb"></i></h1>
       <div id="quizContainer"></div>
       <div id="buttonContainer">
               <button id="retry">TRY AGAIN</button>
               <button id="check">CHECK SCORE</button>
           </div>
           <div id="results"></div>
       </section>
</main>
   <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


* {
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
   font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif; 
   color: white;
}

main::before {
   content: '';
   background-image:linear-gradient(
       115deg,
       rgba(236, 225, 203, 0.5),
       rgba(228, 203, 163, 0.5)
     ), url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/1695052/pexels-photo-1695052.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500)
   ;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   z-index: -1;
 background-position: center;
 filter: grayscale(45%); 
}

#toggleBtns {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-self: center;
   text-align: center;
   margin-top: 70px;
} 

#toggleBtns button {
   width: 60px;
   font-weight: bolder;
   height: 40px;
   cursor: pointer;
}

.active, .btn button:hover {
   border: 2px solid turquoise;
}

#black {
   background: rgba(37, 37, 36);
   color: white;
}

h1{
   text-align: center;
   letter-spacing: 3px;
   font-size: 30px;
}

i {
   margin: 20px;
}

#quizSection {
   max-width: 800px;
   min-width: 450px;
   background: rgba(37, 37, 36, 0.9);
   border-radius: 20px;
   overflow: hidden;
   margin: 50px auto;
}

h3 {
   margin: 50px auto;
   border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(116, 116, 110, 0.9);
   max-width: 700px;
   padding: 30px;
   letter-spacing: 2px;
   font-weight: bolder;
}

p {
   font-size: 30px;
   margin: 100px auto;
   text-align: center;
}

input {
   margin-left: 50px;
   margin-right: 30px;
}

label {
   margin-left: 20px;
   font-size: 18px;
}

ul {
   list-style: none;
}

li {
   line-height: 2;
}

#buttonContainer{
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   margin: 100px auto;
   text-align: center;
}

#buttonContainer button{
   padding: 10px 20px;
   width: 100px;
   height: 50px;
   background: turquoise;
   font-weight: bold;
   border: none;
   border-radius: 10px;
   margin: 15px;
   cursor: pointer;
   color: rgba(37, 37, 36);
}

#buttonContainer button:hover {
   background: rgb(17, 199, 84);
   transition: ease-in-out 0.5s;
}
```